# Django get True/False if field has data

Tags: django

In a Django queryset I have the following:

```
class Address(models.Model):
   building  
   town
   geo_lat
   geo_lng

queryset = Address.objects.all()
```

What i want to do is return True or False field if both geo fields are set. This would allow me to show that we need to update geo data as some are missing.

I assume I need to annotate or something but cant find what i need to use. I dont want to filter out any, but add an extra field I can use to test if true or false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on the right lines with Annotate, we can use the Case, When expression to achieve what i needed.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case

```
Address.objects.all().annotate(
   geo_set=Case(
       When(geo_lat__isnull=False, geo_lng__isnull=False, then=True),
       default=False,
       output_field=BooleanField(),
   ),
)
```